# Spark load settings from multiple configuration files

Tags: apache-spark

Spark reads the default configurations from `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`.

You can also change the default location using the `--properties-file [FILE]` command-line argument when using (say) `spark-submit`.

What I want to do is load additional arguments from a file without having to replace the default ones. That is, I want spark to load the properties from `spark-defaults.conf` and load more properties from another file. Now, in case there are properties defined in both, I would prefer if the last configuration file wins.

**Is this supported by default in Spark?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr No.

As described in the Spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties), here is the order of preference for configuration:

"*Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file.*"

Given this, I would use [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) in my driver code to load a custom configuration file and set whatever I find directly on the `SparkConf`. Anything set there will take precedence over any prior configurations from elsewhere.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! It seems though that for spark-shell you can't really do much. The spark context is already created at start time and you can no longer change its configuration parameters to add (say) more cores or more executors memory, so this approach will work for spark-submit apps but not for spark-shell, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say, "spark-shell you can't really do much." It does as much as the community has asked for; if there were demand for changes, there would be tickets and pull requests. Regardless, the same documentation link says, "*The Spark shell and spark-submit tool support two ways to load configurations dynamically...*" This implies that `spark-submit` and the shell are configured identically.

Comment: Is there any way to specify a configuration file while starting sparkR session. Looking for an answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805162/starting-sparkr-session-using-external-config-file

Comment: The "order of preference" cited in this response has little to do with the original question, which is a way to add/overwrite selected properties from an additional configuration file without losing the defaults in spark-defaults.conf file. This seems not to be possible, but it's not clearly stated in the documentation, and it clearly can not be deduced from the quoted text.