# Starting SparkR session using external config file

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

I have an RStudio driver instance which is connected to a Spark Cluster. I wanted to know if there is any way to actually connect to Spark cluster from RStudio using an external configuration file which can specify the number of executors, memory and other spark parameters. I know we can do it using the below command

```
sparkR.session(sparkConfig = list(spark.cores.max='2',spark.executor.memory = '8g'))
```

I am specifically looking for a method which takes spark parameters from an external file to start the sparkR session.

Answer (score 2):

Spark uses standardized configuration layout with `spark-defaults.conf` used for specifying configuration option. This file should be located in one of the following directories:

- `SPARK_HOME/conf`
- `SPARK_CONF_DIR`

All you have to do is to configure `SPARK_HOME` or `SPARK_CONF_DIR` environment variables and put configuration there.

Each Spark installation comes with template files you can use as an inspiration.

Comment: What I actually need is that I should be able to pass an external spark configuration file through RStudio while connecting to spark so that it does not use the default configurations from spark-defaults.conf file